# Outlook REST API Error: ErrorTooManyObjectsOpened

Tags: outlook, office365, outlook-restapi

I receive this error when syncing messages:

```
"code": "ErrorTooManyObjectsOpened",

"message": "Too many concurrent connections opened., 
Cannot open mailbox /o=ExchangeLabs
/ou=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/cn=Recipients
```

Comment: Just FYI, it's a 429 Rate Limit Exceeded Error caused by making calls to getAttachments() in parallel. I can fetch attachments in series, but is there a more performant approach?